# Jmeter load distribution

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-generator

How to emulate different loads from LG's for single thread group (i.e My First LG should emulate only 200 users, second LG should emulate 50users and my third LG should emulate 250 users)

IS it possible in Jmeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use distributed testing - you can take the following approach:

1. Define number of virtual users in the Thread Group using [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function as `${__P(users,)}`
2. On your load generator machines locate *user.properties* file (it lives in /bin folder of your JMeter installation) and add the following line to it:

   - `users=200` - on the 1st LG
   - `users=50` - on the 2nd LG
   - `users=250` - on the 3rd LG
   - etc.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and ways of setting and overriding them.

Comment: Hi  Dmitri T,  your solutions perfectly works only in GUI mode, can you give solution for same in NON-GUI  mode.

Comment: Hi  Dmitri T,  your solutions perfectly works only in GUI mode, can you give solution for same in NON-GUI  mode.  when ever i am running a script in non GUI mode it is taking 1:6 ratio. (ex. if i am running 10  users in gui mode it shows result for 10 users , same if we are running 10 users in NON-GUI (command mode) it shows 60 users result ,  20 users  it give 120 users result .....       kindly provide solution.    Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi Dmitri T, But in Non-GUI it is not supporting if possible kindly provide some KT step by step pls.   Regards, Shaik Mohammed Ali